# JsException(TypeError: Failed to fetch)

Tags: python, html, pyscripter

When I try to import a pyscript source code to my HTML it shows a "JsException(TypeError: Failed to fetch)" error.

**helloworld.py**

`print("Hello World")`

**testPyscript.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <py-script src="helloworld.py">
        ("Another Text Test")
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and found the answer here: [PyScript: Loading Python Code in the Browser](https://www.jhanley.com/pyscript-loading-python-code-in-the-browser/)

The problem is `<py-script src="helloworld.py">` do not support loading local files, you need a server for the browser to load it...

Go into the folder you keep the files and run `python -m http.server 80` and then, on the browser, go to `localhost/testPyscript.html`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your directory which contains helloworld.py and testPyscript.html need to run in localhost, open your folder in vsCode and install live server from extensions then in your right bottom corner press on Go Live. you will be directed to the default browser with the expected output from helloworld.py

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and was able to write this up. As mentioned you must host the project directory from a local hosted server.

link to original post:
[Error "JsException (TypeError: Failed to fetch)" while trying to run using Python and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72344488/error-jsexception-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-while-trying-to-run-using-pytho)

Defining script environment path, must be placed in head tag.

```html
      <py-env>
        - paths:
          - ./pytest.py
      </py-env>
```

Here is the example code to retrieve python output and inject into html format.
code example:

## index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
      <py-env>
        - paths:
          - ./pytest.py
      </py-env>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Update HTML from PYTHON</h1>
    <b> <label id="output"></label></b>
    <py-script>
      from pytest import function
      pyscript.write('output', function())
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## pytest.py

```py
def function():

    output = 'CONGRATS!'


    return ('Your Data has been extracted from a python script: '+''.join(output))
```