# Error "JsException (TypeError: Failed to fetch)" while trying to run using Python and HTML

Tags: python, html, pyscript

I have this project where I have to display the date time on my website using Python and HTML by using [PyScript](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript). I have two files;

#### File *source.py*

```
import datetime as dt

pyscript.write('date',dt.datetime.today())
```

#### File *index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>hi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="date"></div>
    <py-script src="source.py"></py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I reload my website the page displays this: `JsException (TypeError: Failed to fetch)`. How do I fix this error and what is the explanation behind this occurrence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyScript: how can I fix the "blocked by CORS policy" error when trying to load a Python script from a separate file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72122355/pyscript-how-can-i-fix-the-blocked-by-cors-policy-error-when-trying-to-load-a)

Comment: Open the browser tools and post the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting this error is because py-script needs a server to pull the contents from. You can simply navigate to your projects directory and open a new terminal window, or simply cd into that folder path. Next, once you are in the directory run this command

> $ python -m http.server 8080

This will run a localhost server displaying all contents from that directory.
On your browser now you should be able to access it by entering in the address bar:

> localhost:8080

Lastly, you must define the python script in the head tag. e.g.

```html
<py-env>
  - paths:
    - ./file.py
</py-env>
```

code example:

## index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
      <py-env>
        - paths:
          - ./pytest.py
      </py-env>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Update HTML from PYTHON</h1>
    <b> <label id="output"></label></b>
    <py-script>
      from pytest import function
      pyscript.write('output', function())
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## pytest.py

```py
def function():

    output = 'CONGRATS!'


    return ('Your Data has been extracted from a python script: '+''.join(output))
```

Answer (score -1):

Was your URL look like this and said failed after pressing the reload button in Chrome:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb3Pk.png)

Use the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension in Visual Studio Code to solve this error. Because you need a server for [PyScript](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript) to work.

[Live Server extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yURvi.png)